# MySQL Split Concat?

Tags: mysql

I have a question, and I feel like I have done this before but I cannot get the logic right, I have data coming in with this format

wedding-emotional

party-emotional

life-emotional

right now I am doing a group_concat to combine them with this as a separator "|" as they are all in the same category (emotional) but isn't there a way to eliminate the "-emotional" before the concat in the select statement? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want:

```
group_concat(replace(your_column_name,'-emotional','') separator '|')
```

Though that will remove -emotional even if it isn't at the end; if that is a problem, use regexp_replace, which requires mysql 8:

```
regexp_replace(your_column_name,'-emotional$','')
```